# Extra rectangle gets drawn after label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, panel

I want to include the colored panel below into my form:

[image]

For this I have created custom panel which will change Border color based on Radio Button selection. My panel code is

**InfoPanel.cs**

```cs
 class InfoPanel : Panel
 {
     private Color colorBorder = Color.Transparent;

     public InfoPanel()
         : base()
     {
         this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
     }

     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         base.OnPaint(e);
         e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
             new Pen(
                 new SolidBrush(colorBorder), 2),
                 e.ClipRectangle);            
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(colorBorder), 0), 50, 0, 50, 50); //drawing a line to split the child & parent info panel
     }

     public Color BorderColor
     {
         get
         {
             return colorBorder;
         }
         set
         {
             colorBorder = value;
         }
     }
 }
```

In my form,
1. created one parent Info Panel
2. created one child panel with Picture box
3. One label in parent info panel to show the information

Now for the parent panel I am changing the colors [back, border] & text based on user selection & for child panel I am not changing border color but updating back color based on user selection.

Below is the code for changing the panel colors, image, text update:

```cs
private void rbIPAddress_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbIPAddress.Checked)
    {                
        ParentInfoPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFEE");
        ParentInfoPanel.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DADA85");
        ChildInfoPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F6F6D8");
        InfoPanelPictureBox.Image = Template.InfoPanelInfoImage;
        Infolabel.Text = "IP Address is already configured. You can switch to Forward Lookup Zone by choosing other configuration. *IP Address \ncan be either LB IP Address.";
        txtBoxIPAddress.Enabled = true;
        textBoxPort.Enabled = true;   
    }
    else
    {
        Infolabel.Text = "";
        txtBoxIPAddress.Text = "";
        txtBoxIPAddress.Enabled = false;
        textBoxPort.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void rbForwardLookupZone_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbForwardLookupZone.Checked)
    {
        ParentInfoPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFEE");
        ParentInfoPanel.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DADA85");
        ChildInfoPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F6F6D8");
        InfoPanelPictureBox.Image = Template.InfoPanelInfoImage;
        Infolabel.Text = "Forward Lookup Zone is already configured. You can switch to IP Address by choosing other configuration and \nchanging port number will affect Firewall rules.";
        textBoxControlPlane.Enabled = true;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxControlPlane.Text))
        {
            textBoxControlPlane.Text = Constants.DefaultControlPlaneDomain;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Infolabel.Text = "";
        textBoxControlPlane.Text = "";
        textBoxControlPlane.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** used next line character to display label text in multiple line

Output: [image] [image] Everything is ok but in the end of label text I am getting another rectangle box. I'm wondering why is showing like this? Am I doing wrong? Please help me on this.

Comment: [Worth reading](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwje3MSHl4flAhXBzKQKHRpaBM8QFjACegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F12062019%2Fwhat-is-the-difference-between-painteventargs-cliprectangle-and-painteventargs-g&usg=AOvVaw3_w2jV9B0Hn7XoxxMJBH3r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `e.ClipRectangle`. It informs you *which portion* of the control needs to be redrawn. This is sometimes only a small part of the control rather than the whole thing (in your case the area of the extra rectangle). Always draw the control's full rectangle instead.

Also, you must dispose of both the `Pen` and `SolidBrush`. Failing to do so causes memory leaks. Utilize the [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

```
using(SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colorBorder))
using(Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 2))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width - 1, this.ClientSize.Height - 1));
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 50, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: @saravana : Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!